# How to render root layout in Marionettejs?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Based on this [fact](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.5/marionette.application.html#application-regions), Region in Application is deprecated. How do you render the root layout? Simplely new the RootLayout() will not render the layout view. I know call region show() function will render layout, but since there is no region on Application object. How do you render the root layout?

The document suggest the following way, but it doesn't work.

I defined root layout like this:

```
var RootView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  el: 'body'
});
```

Then render the root layout like this:

```
var canvasApp = new Marionette.Application();
canvasApp.on('start', function() {
    canvasApp.rootView = new RootLayout();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    canvasApp.start();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be as simple as

```
var RootView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend();
var rootView = new RootView();
rootView.render().$el.appendTo( document.body ); // or a selector
```

or

```
var RootView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend();
var rootView = new RootView({ el: '#app' });
rootView.render();
```

or, as in your case

```
var RootView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  el: 'body'
});
var rootView = new RootView();
rootView.render(); // just remember to render it
```

Answer (score 0):

define the regions inside the LayoutView and then show desired views

```
var RootView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
  el: 'body,
  regions: {
    menu: "#menu",
    content: "#content"
   }
});

RootView.getRegion('menu').show(new MenuView());
RootView.getRegion('content').show(new ContentView());
```

you can find more information here http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.layoutview.html#basic-usage

Answer (score 0):

It might be an old question, but I was able to solve the issue like so:

```
var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions({
  mainRegion: '#app'
});

App.mainRegion.show(new RootView());

App.start();
```